# how to skip labels like category using GMAIL API

Tags: .net, gmail-api

I am using GMAIL API over REST Interface to read mails. I could see an API to get Label list for a user mailbox but my question is that can we differentiate between standard and custom folders and other category. Can I skip the categories like Forum, Personal, updates, social and also Unseen, UNREAD labels. Is there any enum defined for it because if I consider the names then it might get changed for different languages?

Thanks
Haseena

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The resources returned by various label methods have a "type" field that indicates whether they are system-defined or user-defined labels: [Users.labels - Gmail API — Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/labels)

Comment: can I skip categories? because if I change the language then category name might change.Is there any way to skip?

Comment: If you are referring to tabbed inbox categories, they are system labels and will be skipped if you skip system labels: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/labels.  These enum values are always the same and do not change according to language settings.

Comment: correct, all the system labels are documented static label identifiers--they are not language specific as they're not expected to be shown directly to users.